# git cherry-pick failing because of merge conflict

Tags: git, github

I am using `git cherry-pick` to add specific commit SHAs to a particular branch:

```
git cherry-pick 12345
error: commit 12345 is a merge but no -m option was given.
fatal: cherry-pick failed
```

(Pretend `12345` is a commit SHA.)

I've tried several other variations but they all fail:

```
git cherry-pick 12345 -m
git cherry-pick -m 12345
etc.
```

**Not sure how to interpret the error message or figure out what the fix is.** Any ideas?

Comment: Are you aware that you are cherry picking a merge commit, and do you really want to be doing this?  You can specify `-m` and choose which parent you want to follow, but maybe you don't intend to do this at all.

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen (+1) - I actually have a long laundry list of `git cherry-pick <sha>` commands to run, this is the 4th in the list and is the first one to fail, the first 3 were successful. When running `cherry-pick`, is the order of the commits/commands important?

Comment: @smeed The problem here isn't the order, it's the merge commit.

Comment: OK @TimBiegeleisen so I *think* I'm hearing that its OK to skip the merge commit, since it doesn't apply to what I'm trying to do here (cherry pick)?

Comment: Why do you think you need the merge commit in the first place?  If it contains changes you want, then maybe you need it.

Comment: Ahh gotchya, so **yes** I am 100% sure I want to do this. But as you can see I have specified `-m` several ways and am still getting errors. What should my exact command be?

Comment: Seems you completely changed your question. Never do that. Ask a new question instead. You can rollback your question by clicking on "edited ... ago".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the sequence of commits passed to git cherry-pick indeed matters.

Consider your first commit `A` introduced a new line, and the next commit `B` modified the same line. if the commits are picked in the wrong order, then commit `B` has nothing to patch, even if that didn't fail, then commit `A` would add the un-patched line back, probably not what you want, right?

And regarding merge commits, if it introduced changes, then it must be included, too.

Also, usually you don't pass a long list of commits to `git cherry-pick`, you can use revision range syntax to specify a series of commits, please refer to the **EXAMPLES** section in the manual: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick

Comment: Thanks @ryenus if my commit is a merge commit and my SHA number is `12345` what is the exact command I need to use here? Because I've tried `git cherry-pick -m 12345` and `git cherry-pick 12345 -m` and both fail...

Comment: @smeeb it could be `git cherry-pick 12345 -m 1` or `git cherry-pick 12345 -m 2`. `1` and `2` mean the 1st and 2nd parent of `12345`. But in your case you don't need to cherry-pick a merge commit.

Comment: Thanks @ElpieKay (+1) - how can I apply the merge commit to my branch then(if, like you say, I don't need to or can't cherry pick a merge commit)?

Comment: @smeeb If you have cherry-picked both or all of its parents, then just ignore it. In this case, when you run `git cherry-pick 12345 -m 1` or `git cherry-pick 12345 -m 2`, it returns something like `The previous cherry-pick is now empty, possibly due to conflict resolution`. A non-conflict merge commit does not introduce changes. The changes are from its parents. So if we just pick the merge commit, we need to choose which parent to use. But `-m <n>` seems to abandon the n-th parent's changes.

Comment: @smeeb, something like `git diff commit_before_merge merge_commit | git apply -`, you should know which parent of the merge_commit is the one you should use for commit_before_merge, in case `git cherry-pick -m` isn't that obvious.